# Is sleeping a necessary condition for Tahajjud (night prayer)?

Tags: salat, tahajjud

I want to know whether or not sleeping is a necessary condition for [Tahajjud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tahajjud)?

For example this fatwa says that Tahajjud means praying after sleeping:

> Tahajjud means specifically praying at night, and some scholars limited it to prayers that are offered at night after sleeping.  (https://islamqa.info/en/143240)

Answer (score 4):

It is not mandatory to sleep after isha if you want to pray tahajjud.
According to the [this](http://islamhelpline.net/node/2656) fatwa it is not obligatory to do tahajjud after sleep.

According to [this fatwa](http://islamqa.org/hanafi/askimam/14500),

> "It was the noble habit of Rasulullah (Sallallaahu Alayhi Wasallam) to sleep and then wake up for tahajjud. If one is unable to wake up for tahajjud, then one may perform tahajjud before going to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Assalamualikum,
It is the Sunnah of the Messenger of Allah (saws) and best if one sleeps after Isha and wakes up again to offer the Tahajjud or late night prayers, but it is not obligatory. If one finds it difficult to wake up again for Tahajjud, then there is no harm if one offers these voluntary prayers after the Isha prayers or before one goes to sleep.
May Allah Guide us all,Ameen.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Answers here should be elaborate, and focused on answering the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help), and refer to [how to answer questions](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).